# Jquery .on('change' does not detect javascript inputed field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

see following snip of code

```
 $(document).on('input','#id1, #id2, #id3', function(){
        $id1 = $('#retail').val(); 
        $id2 = $('#tax').val(); 
        $id3 = $('#discount_per_unit').val();
        $total = Number($id1) + Number($id2) - Number($id3);
        $('#total').val($total);

    });
```

now, user gets to input field for #id1, #id2. but I have a Ajax fill in #id3 for the user depending on conditions. the `.on(input` or `.on(change` event only detect user input but not the Ajax input. So is there a way to get jquery to detect Ajax input as well.

basically I have a drop down menu user can pick, and Ajax will take the drop down value to get an additioanl data and auto fill into id3 input field. look something like this.

```
$('#id3').val($somevalue);
```

but my .on("change" does not detect when user picked a different drop down option so the #id3 is updated but my calcuation that uses id1 though id3 did not update unless I change something on id1 or id2.

Comment: A simple solution would be to break out your code into a function and call it from both `on(input`, `on(change` as well as on the `success` callback from your ajax.

Comment: What you mean about ajax input? You mean a change done in a ajax return? If so, you need to trigger the change manually. Besides that, you need to use `.on("change", ... `

Comment: What about using: `$('#id3').val($somevalue).trigger('input')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update `$('#id3').val($somevalue);` didn't trigget any event, they are based on user's actions.

If you want to manually trigger one you can do

```
$('#id3').val($somevalue).trigger('change') // or 'input'
```

Comment: was just about to answer my own question. I stumbled upon something similar and this works.